# How to insert data in to table from one variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

How to insert this data in to table from one variable?

Table1 has fields: ID NAME ADDRESS

Data $strtoalvalue= 1 jam usa 2 dara usa 3 david usa

HOw to insert data from  $strtoalvalue to Table1 by using PHP and mysql.

Comment: 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INSERT
2. http://php.net/mysql_query
3. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
- or -
4. http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 3):

You can do a lot with a single string if you format it and then convert it into an array.

These are two commands that are very useful for this:

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

You said your data is "1 jam usa 2 dara usa 3 david usa", so lets put this into a usable string format:

```
$strtoalvalue= "1,jam,usa|2,dara,usa|3,david,usa";
```

Next, you use explode() to turn this into an array:

```
$firstarray = explode("|",$strtovalue);
```

Now you have an array with these three strings in it:

```
$firstarray[0] = "1,jam,usa"
$firstarray[1] = "2,dara,usa"
$firstarray[2] = "3,david,usa"
```

next, you can loop through $firstarray, and convert each of it's strings into an array containing the values:

```
foreach($firstarray as $datastring){
    $secondarray[] = explode(',',$data_string);
}
```

now your $secondarray contains 3 arrays, which contain your data separated into individual pieces. all you have to do now is access it like so:

```
foreach($secondarray as $data_array){
    $data_id = $data_array[0];
    $data_name = $data_array[1];
    $data_address = $data_array[2];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, address) VALUES ($data_id, '$data_name', '$data_address')";
    // execute your SQL here
}
```

However, this is not secure, you will want to escape your data before concatenating it into the SQL string like that, otherwise your script is prone to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)